# How do I use a JS Map in lab.js?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dictionary

I try to save drag and dropable items on their last position.
For this I safe the item and the target the last have been dropped on as a map. But lab.js won't give me the data saved in the map at the end.
This is the code for the function and the map

```
 <script>
    
const itemToTarget = new Map();
const targetToItem = new Map();


function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

  if (ev.type == "dragstart") {
    var item = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
    targetToItem.delete(item.parentNode.id);
  }
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  if (ev.target.id.includes("item")) return;

  if (targetToItem.has(ev.target.id)) return;

  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  itemToTarget.set(data, ev.target.id);
  targetToItem.set(ev.target.id, data);
}

</script>


</head>
```

And I define the items and targets in the html as follow:

```
<div align="center" class="divcenter">
 <div class="container">

  <div id="item2" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(108, 129, 100); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>

  <div id="item3" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(59, 134, 144); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ></div>

  <div id="item4" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(143, 111, 164); border: 2px solid lightgray;"draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item5" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(144, 118, 96); border: 2px solid lightgray;"draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item6" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(88, 132, 115); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item7" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(156, 109, 137); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item8" class="elem1"style="background: rgb(57, 133, 156); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item9" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(159, 109, 124); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item10" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(128, 115, 178); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item11" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(59, 132, 167); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item12" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(146, 112, 153); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item13" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(131, 123, 93); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item14" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(53, 131, 180); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item15" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(63, 135, 130); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>

  <div id="item16" class="elem1" style="background: rgb(158, 110, 111); border: 2px solid lightgray;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container"> </div>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div id="targert17" class="elem1" style="background:rgb(55,129,193);"></div>
  <div id="targert18" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white"></div>  
  <div id="targert19" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert20" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert21" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert22" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert23" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert24" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert25" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert26" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert27" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert28" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert29" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert30" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert31" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
  <div id="targert32" class="elem1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background:white;"></div>
 </div>
```

Anyone knows how I tell lab.js to give me the final state of the map?

I tried using the two following solutions I came up with in the script section of lab.js:

`this.state.itemToTarget = itemToTarget`

and the following idea from Stack:

```
    var myStr = ""
    // Creating header
    for(let key of itemToTarget.keys()){
      myStr += key+","
    } 
    myStr = myStr.slice(0,-1)+"\r\n";



   // Creating each row
 for(let i = 0; i<firstValue.length; i++){
     var row = ""
     for(let key of itemToTarget.keys()){
      if(map.get(key)[i]){
       row += map.get(key)[i]+","
      }else{
        row += ","
      }
     }
     myStr += row.slice(0, -1)+"\r\n";
    }


fs.writeFileSync('./mycsv.csv',myStr);
```